# matrix python numpy with positif and negative value

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

i want to generate a diagonal matrix with size such as nxn

Answer (score 2):

This is a [toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix), you can use SciPy's [`linalg.toeplitz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.toeplitz.html) to construct such a pattern. You can look at its implementation code [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.8.1/scipy/linalg/_special_matrices.py#L139-L199) which uses from [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) under the hood.

```
>>> toeplitz(-np.arange(3), np.arange(3))
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [-1,  0,  1],
       [-2, -1,  0]])

>>> toeplitz(-np.arange(6), np.arange(6))
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [-2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2],
       [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0]])
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know the name :)

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to write as a custom function:

```
def diagonal(N):
    a = np.arange(N)
    return a-a[:,None]

diagonal(3)
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [-1,  0,  1],
       [-2, -1,  0]])

diagonal(6)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [-2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2],
       [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0]])
```